# Stub out the global craft() object for PHPUnit tests

Tags: php, tests

As best I can tell, the 'mockBuilder' function is exactly what I want, and based on other examples, should work.

Am I missing something?
How can I stub out the global craft() object?

#### under test:

```
<?php

namespace Craft;


class JobsVariable
{

     // Grab all Jobss
     public function jobs()
      {
            return craft();
      }
 }
```

#### test file:

```
    <?php

    namespace Craft;

    require_once 'www/craftcms/plugins/jobs/variables/JobsVariable.php';


    class JobsVariableTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
    {



        public function testJobs()
        {


            $craft = $this->getMockBuilder('\\Craft')
                ->disableOriginalConstructor()
                ->setMethods(array('craft'))
                ->getMock();


            $craft->method('craft')->willReturn('xxx');


            $jobs = new \Craft\JobsVariable();
            $this->assertEquals('xxx', $jobs->jobs());

        }
    }
```

#### output:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function Craft\craft()
```

Comment: This is a rather extensive self-conversation @nullsteph! Would you kindly accept whichever of your answers you feel is best?

Answer (score 1):

Whew...this seems to do the trick!
Hopefully this is an appropriate way to handle things.

I created a new Craft class file in the 'tests' dir.  There I can stub out any `\Craft\craft()` methods the class under test depends on.

#### stub class \tests\Craft

```
<?php

class Craft {

    public function __construct()
    {
    }

    public function jobs()
    {
        return 'xxx';
    }
    public function getJobs()
    {
        return 'xxx';
    }

    public function craft()
    {
        return $this;
    }
}
```

#### in the test class

```
<?php

namespace Craft;

require_once '/www/craftcms/plugins/jobs/variables/JobsVariable.php';
require_once '/www/craftcms/tests/Craft.php';


class JobsVariableTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{

    public function testJobs()
    {
        $jobs = new \Craft\JobsVariable();
        $this->assertEquals('xxx', $jobs->jobs());

    }
}
function craft()
{
    return new \Craft;
}
```

#### allows me to test this function...

```
public function jobs()
{
    return craft()->jobs();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

...and because the actual test method to get mocked looks like this:
`craft()->jobs->getJobs()`

I can mock this up by adding a class to my stubbed out \test\Craft class;

```
<?php

class Craft {

    public $jobs;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->jobs = new Jobs;
    }
}


class Jobs{

    public function __construct(){
        var_dump('new jobs');
    }


    public function getJobs(){
        return 'xxx';
    }
}
```

Now I can return dummy test data ('xxx'), instead of letting the code make  network requests for real data.