# PHPUnit testing for Craft plugins or controllers

Tags: plugin-development

Is it possible to implement PHPUnit into Craft CMS? If so, where can I find a good explanation or tutorial? I already tried a Github link for a plugin (testing the plugin).

But I am new to both but really want to TDD the plugins. Any example pages or a quick guide would be great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a good example of testing with PHPUnit in a Craft plugin here: https://github.com/selvinortiz/craft.loath and an example on how to stub out the global `craft()` class here: [Stub out the global craft() object for PHPUnit tests](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/10049/stub-out-the-global-craft-object-for-phpunit-tests)

Note that testing in Craft should be a lot easier/convenient in the upcoming Craft 3.

Comment: In the upcoming Craft 3, it would be great if there came a section where Craft 3 and PHPUnit had a nice tutorial for beginners to write good plugins?

Anyway thanks for the answer!