# Unit Testing with current version of Craft

Tags: plugin-development, tests

Has Craft stopped shipping with unit tests? I'm trying to unit test a plugin and have noticed from several previous answers (e.g [PHPUnit testing for Craft plugins or controllers](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/16324/phpunit-testing-for-craft-plugins-or-controllers)) that it was possible at some stage using Craft's local tests. Have these since been removed? There no longer seems to be a tests folder inside the latest download of Craft/app.

What is the current best practice for setting up Unit Tests using Craft 2 in a plugin?

Comment: That's correct, Craft no longer ships with PHPunit included. It was removed in [Craft 2.5.2750](https://craftcms.com/changelog#2-5-2750), which was released on Dec 1, 2015.

Comment: So whats the best way to bootstrap craft for unit testing in a plugin?

Comment: That I don't know. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I found a bootstrap that works for me apart from an issue with the database connection.

I can't find the link now but here is the code:

```php
<?php
define("CRAFT_ENVIRONMENT", "dev");
// PHP sucks at resolving symlinked directories
define('CRAFT_BASE_PATH', realpath(str_replace("plugins/myplugin", '', dirname(__FILE__))).'/');

// Define app constants
defined('CRAFT_APP_PATH')          || define('CRAFT_APP_PATH',          CRAFT_BASE_PATH.'app/');
defined('CRAFT_CONFIG_PATH')       || define('CRAFT_CONFIG_PATH',       CRAFT_BASE_PATH.'config/');
defined('CRAFT_VENDOR_PATH')       || define('CRAFT_VENDOR_PATH',       CRAFT_BASE_PATH.'app/vendor/');
defined('CRAFT_FRAMEWORK_PATH') || define('CRAFT_FRAMEWORK_PATH', CRAFT_APP_PATH.'framework/');;
defined('CRAFT_PLUGINS_PATH')      || define('CRAFT_PLUGINS_PATH',      CRAFT_BASE_PATH.'plugins/');
defined('CRAFT_STORAGE_PATH')      || define('CRAFT_STORAGE_PATH',      CRAFT_BASE_PATH.'storage/');
defined('CRAFT_TEMPLATES_PATH')    || define('CRAFT_TEMPLATES_PATH',    CRAFT_BASE_PATH.'templates/');
defined('CRAFT_TRANSLATIONS_PATH') || define('CRAFT_TRANSLATIONS_PATH', CRAFT_BASE_PATH.'translations/');
defined('YII_TRACE_LEVEL')          || define('YII_TRACE_LEVEL', 3);
// Load Yii
require_once CRAFT_APP_PATH.'framework/yiit.php';
Yii::$enableIncludePath = false;
require_once CRAFT_APP_PATH.'Craft.php';
require_once CRAFT_APP_PATH.'etc/web/WebApp.php';
require_once CRAFT_APP_PATH.'Info.php';
// Craft shits itself if there is no server or request path
$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] = 'dev.copywheat';
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = '/';
// Load test database
$config = require_once CRAFT_APP_PATH.'etc/config/test.php';
$config['params']['dbConfig'] = array();

// Create app instance
$app = new \Craft\WebApp($config);
// Load plugin
require_once CRAFT_PLUGINS_PATH.'myplugin/mypluginPlugin.php';
```

I'm still having issues with the db connection.  Have had to resort to modifying the `craft/app/etc/config/defaults.db` in order to override the environment file which does work for me at the moment.